# How to get user information from Twitter in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a flutter application where I am integrating twitter login(without firebase).
The twitter login is working fine, I am able to make the login using twitter.
I am using the package: flutter_twitter: ^1.1.3
But after login I am only getting the username of the user.

Is there any way to get the email address, profile picture and other personal information of the user?

Comment: Please check this comment https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/419#issuecomment-264560103 , I have get email after User authentication settings changes on twitter development portal.

Answer (score 1):

Your package seems to only manage authentication, you will need to make HTTP request yourself to Twitter API if you want to fetch any other data.

Based on [Twitter Users API Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users) you cannot get user's email address but you can get the profile picture url (`profile_image_url`) or informations such as the user's `name` and `username`.

I let you refer to the [API full documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index#twitter-api-v2) to see all informations you might be able to fetch.

Comment: there's example or docs for how to fetch data from twitter api using http?

Comment: You can find it in the links I've provided you got an Example requests to show what kind of HTTP request you need to perform and an Example responses to demonstrate what kind of JSON response you get.